# Using ffmpeg's avcodec_receive_frame() and why do I get these vertical lines in the decodec image sometimes

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, decode

I'm using the modern ffmpeg API which instructs me to use `avcodec_send_packet` and `avcodec_receive_frame`. There are literally [no examples of usage in github](https://github.com/search?q=avcodec_recive_frame&type=Code) so I couldn't compare with other code.

My code kinda works, but sometimes, for less than a second or two, the video gets decoded like this:

[image]

I thought it was a buffer size problem, so I increased from

```
const size_t bufferSize = 408304;
```

to

```
const size_t bufferSize = 10408304;
```

Just to see but the problem persists.

(the video size is 1920x1080 and this happens even when there's little motion in the screen)

Here's my decoder class which sends the decoded data to OpenGL in the line 
`this->frameUpdater->updateData(avFrame->data, avFrame->width, avFrame->height);`

```
    void  FfmpegDecoder::decodeFrame(uint8_t* frameBuffer, int frameLength)
{
    if (frameLength <= 0) return;

    int frameFinished = 0;

    AVPacket* avPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!avPacket) std::cout << "av packet error" << std::endl;

    avPacket->size = frameLength;
    avPacket->data = frameBuffer;

    //Disable ffmpeg annoying output
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET); 

    int sendPacketResult = avcodec_send_packet(avCodecContext, avPacket);
    if (!sendPacketResult) {
        int receiveFrameResult = avcodec_receive_frame(avCodecContext, avFrame);
        if (!receiveFrameResult) {
            this->frameUpdater->updateData(avFrame->data, avFrame->width, avFrame->height);
        } else if ((receiveFrameResult < 0) && (receiveFrameResult != AVERROR(EAGAIN)) && (receiveFrameResult != AVERROR_EOF)) {
            std::cout << "avcodec_receive_frame returned error " << receiveFrameResult /*<< *av_err2str(result).c_str()*/ << std::endl;
        } else {
            switch (receiveFrameResult) {
                //Not exactly an error, we just have to wait for more data
                case AVERROR(EAGAIN):
                    break;
                //To be done: what does this error mean? I think it's literally the end of an mp4 file
                case AVERROR_EOF:
                    std::cout << "avcodec_receive_frame AVERROR_EOF" << std::endl;
                    break;
                //To be done: describe what error is this in std cout before stopping
                default:
                    std::cout << "avcodec_receive_frame returned error, stopping..." << receiveFrameResult /*<< av_err2str(result).c_str()*/ << std::endl;
                    break;
                //Error happened, should break anyway
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        switch (sendPacketResult) {
            case AVERROR(EAGAIN):
                std::cout << "avcodec_send_packet EAGAIN" << std::endl;
                break;
            case AVERROR_EOF:
                std::cout << "avcodec_send_packet AVERROR_EOF" << std::endl;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

I think that people who knows how decoding works might know instantly why the image gets decoded like this. It'd be very helpful to know why. Thanks!

Comment: `There are literally no examples of usage in github`. There literally ARE examples in the GitHub FFmpeg repo. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_video.c

Comment: `updateData()` can not possibly work without line_stride. How is `updateData()` implemented? Does it assume yuv420 planar?

Comment: @szatmary I didn't know there were types of YUV data so I think I'm assuing it's planar

Comment: @szatmary thanks. I just checked the code and it seems that it decodes just like me

Comment: How are you rendering without line_stride?

Comment: @szatmary I don't undrstand the concept of line stride, I just found a code that renders YUV data through OpenGL. You can take a look at my shader here: https://github.com/lucaszanella/orwell/blob/9f4ed99c7fb6712491655260f1e6170c886c5eee/cpp/desktop/OpenGlMaterialQQuickItem.cpp it does YUV to RGB

Comment: That code assumes line_stride = width which is a bad assumption. It also assumes yuv420p. If your input is not 420p, or the decoder produces a different line_stride. This will not work. You can google line_stride to figure that out, and/or use swscale to force correct stride and pixel format.

Comment: @szatmary thanks, I'll certainly do it. I thought that, no matter the input, the output of ffmpeg would always be yuv420p, wouldn't it? Anyways, the problem in the question has nothing to do with it, rigth?

Comment: Ffmpeg will output whatever is input. RGB in RGB out, etc. this is at least pat of the problem, if not the whole problem.